# Android Studio XML formatting not filling screen

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I am working on one of my first apps. One activity of the app includes swiping left and right to scroll through different fragments,  I am using Scroll-View for this. I want each fragment to include multiple elements, but unfortunately Scroll-View only supports a maximum of one direct child element. To work around this, I placed all the views I want in the fragment inside a ConstraintLayout, making the ConstraintLayout the only direct child of the ScrollView. You can see this in my XML code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/gayLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <A BUNCH OF CHILD VIEWS (ImageViews, TextViews, etc.)/>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Unfortunately, this completely messes up the formatting. You can see this in the image below:

[image]

A blue line can be seen in the render underneath all the views. From what I can gather, this is the bottom edge of the inner Constraint-Layout, but the thing is, I have no idea how to move it, and I cannot move any of its child elements below the line. I can make it smaller, just not larger, and there's no way for me to get it to scale to different screen sizes. What would be a better way to group these child elements without having this problem? Thanks!

Comment: This is in the editor, correct? What does it look like when you run your app on a device?

Comment: I suggest that you look at ViewPager to do what you want instead of ScrollView.

Comment: To answer your first question, it looks the exact same on a device as it does in the editor unfortunately. And yeah, I am already using ViewPager2, and in order for it to work you have to add a ScrollView in the code for each fragment. For reference, I am following this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide-2).

Comment: ViewPager2 doesn't require the fragments to use a ScrollView that I can tell. The XML for each fragment just needs a single container to hold its child elements. If these elements overflow a single screen, then a Scroll View is appropriate. Note that the tutorial you are following has the Scroll View as the root component with the children components directly inside it. I suggest you start with this kind of view and work from there. The nesting you currently have is not necessary.